# In Airplay SDK, Iw2DCreateImage return Heap 0 out of memory problem on png larger than 360x360 px

Tags: c++, image, heap-memory, airplay

In Airplay SDK, When my code gets to the following, and if my image.png is larger than 360x360 px I get:
"Heap 0 out of memory. Allocating 1766400 bytes but only 2198280 available (1318780 LFB). 
Increase icf setting [s3e] MemSize (current value is 3145728)."

```
current_image = Iw2DCreateImage( "image.png" );
```

I even tried with the sample that were provided, like (IwUtil - Image)
But get the same error when it reach Upload() to memory.

```
s3eFile* pFile = s3eFileOpen("textures/bigTestTexture.png", "rb");
...
s_Texture->Upload();
```

Anyone know why this is happening? because it shouldn't even be a problem as 360x360 or even 512x512 are small images.

Answer (score 1):

in file app.icf, or something like this(with ext *.icf) place string
`[s3e] 
MemSize = 1766400`
value 1766400 is max memory wich your app use, and it must be greater then i wrote.